# ArrayList Rectangle

Tags: java, arrays, graphics

I am having trouble. I am trying to create a bar graph with an arraylist that a user inputs. I can create one bar, but only one bar will create. I need all of the array inputs to create a bar.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import org.omg.PortableServer.CurrentOperations;


public class BarChart {

private double width;
private double height;
private ArrayList<Double> values;
Random generator = new Random ();

public BarChart(double iniwidth, double iniheight) {
    width = iniwidth;
    height = iniheight;
    values = new ArrayList<Double>();
    generator = new Random();
    }

public void add (double input) {
    values.add(input);
}

public void draw (Graphics g2) {
    double max = Collections.max(values);
    int xleft = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) 
    {
        double barHeight= (max - height);
        width = 50;
        float r = generator.nextFloat();
        float g = generator.nextFloat();
        float b = generator.nextFloat();
        Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
        Rectangle bar = new Rectangle ((int) (xleft + width), (int) height);
        g2.setColor(randomColor);
        ((Graphics2D) g2).fill(bar);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        ((Graphics2D) g2).draw(bar);

    }
    System.out.println(Collections.max(values));
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

All your bars have the same x location, so they are drawing over themselves.  `xLeft` is always 0.  Likely you are forgetting to increment it.

For example:

```
xLeft += width;
```